# Resume interrupted file copy Mac OS X

Tags: networking, osx-snow-leopard

My laptop froze up in the middle of a (large) file copy from my desktop (over a simple LAN). The copy operation was about 2/3 complete when this happened and I was just wondering how (if at all) I can resume the copy operation from where it was interrupted.

I'm on OS X 10.6.6

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. First `cd` into the destination folder (e.g. your locally mounted SMB Network Share)

   ```
   cd /Volumes/Your-SMB-Network-Share/path/to/destination/
   ```
2. Then run `curl` like this:

   ```
   curl -C - -O file:///Users/username/path/to/source/filename
   ```

   - `-C -` aka `--continue-at` byte position `-` which is a shortcut for "where the transfer was interrupted" at the destination file.
   - `-O` tells to use the same file name as on the source which is stated as the last argument in the `file://` notation.
   - Note that whitespaces in the filepaths at source/destination are possible if backslash encoded like this:

     - `cd /Volumes/Your\ SMB\ Network\ Share/path\ to\ destination/`
     - `curl -C - -O file:///Users/username/Movies/Movie\ Name\ with\ spaces.iso`

Comment: I was moving the folder 5sc left disk connection interrupted i tried this and curl returns; curl: Remote file name has no length!
Folder is grayed out and i can enter to the folder. Any suggestion?

Comment:  Worked great on macOS 11.7.4 Big Sur with curl 7.64.1 with the source being a local file on an APFS filesystem and the destination being a SMB Share on an OpenMediaVault NAS. My upload in Finder had aborted. The resume with curl worked perfect: `** Resuming transfer from byte position XXXXXXX`

Comment: I edited the answer into a more structured form and also added instructions how to work with whitespace in folder and file names.