# How to make alias/function in .bash_profile for `curl` that takes an argument?

Tags: mac, bash, terminal.app, curl, .bash-profile

I found this [tip super](https://superuser.com/questions/248365/resume-interrupted-file-copy-mac-os-x) helpful, for using `curl` to resume an interrupted file copy.

The full syntax is:

```
curl -C - -O file:///Volumes/path/to/file
```

I would like to add an alias or function called `resume` to my `.bash_profile` (on Mac) so that I can use something like

```
resume /Volumes/disk1/file
```

I was going to try something like

```
function resume() { ... }
```

but I'm not sure how to pass the argument with the `file:///` prefix.

Answer (score 5):

Functions receive parameters just like scripts, so you can use `$1` to refer to the first argument passed:

```
resume () {
  curl -C - -O "file://$1"
}
```

Note that you don't need both `function` *and* the parens; either one tells bash that it's a function.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, probably because there are spaces in the path. If I do `resume /Volumes/Disk\ 1/Dir\ 1/File\ 1` then curl returns `curl: (37) Couldn't open file /Volumes/Disk` followed by a bunch of HTML code!

Comment: You can put quotes around the argument `curl -C - -O "file://$1"`