# Mac OSX 10.9 resume folder copy to NAS

Tags: macos, networking, mac, curl, file-transfer

I have a really big folder (174GB) that I wanted to move to a NAS using Ethernet. I started the transfer and when it was neary finished the computer stopped (I accidentally disabled caffeine) and the result on the NAS was [this](http://cl.ly/image/0Z221P0s2H08),it is recognized as a folder, and I can navigate into it with terminal, but unluckily cannot click on it to open.

I wanted to finish the copy, so I found [This](https://superuser.com/questions/248365/resume-interrupted-file-copy-mac-os-x) question which suggests to use curl with -O and -C options, but it does not apply to folders.

Is there a way to resume it (It took nearly a day and less than a GB is left), or at least to open it with finder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rsync` to pick-up where you left off, in fact, with `rsync`'s compression, you could have cut the transfer time down a bit.  You will need to enable the `Sharing --> Remote Login` on the remote machine to be able to use `rsync` to/from it.   When you enable `Remote Login`, the `Sharing` panel will display a message that says something like

```
To log in to this computer remotely, type "ssh whmcclos@192.168.0.2"
```

This will be the form of the `rsync` command you will use to copy/pick up where you left off:

```
$ rsync -avz source_folder whmcclos@192.168.0.2:path_relative_to_login_folder
```

So, I can put my `~/iTunes` folder in my remote `~/Downloads` folder, starting, or picking up where it left off with this command, assuming I'm sitting in my login folder:

```
$ rsync -avz iTunes whmcclos@192.168.0.2:Downloads
```

It will prompt for your remote password, construct a file list, and start or pick up transferring files.  The `-a` switch means `archive`, and essentially gives you folder recursion.  The `-z` switch uses compression in the network transfer.  The `-v` switch displays what is happening during the transfer.

This should do the trick for you.  There are many example in the `rsync` `man` page.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. It looks like LaCie 2Big Network 2 NAS does not support ssh unless with an hack, too bad, i'll use the Qnap NAS. Does rsync also work on the same machine? i.e. I have the NAS volume mounted in /Volumes, can I use rsync from Desktop to Volumes?

Comment: Yes, `rsync` works equally well locally to copy and "merge" folders - quite useful, as you know.  Yes, you can use `rysnc` anywhere you have permission to access.  If the source folder ends with a slant (`/`), then the contents of that folder are copied.  The syntax can take some getting used to.  `rsync` is a different protocol than `ssh`; the two may be combined; `rsync` alone and with `ssh` are used to sync datasets over the Internet quite frequently.  Sharing has to be enabled for `rsync` to work, but `ssh` is on a different port altogether, and uses its own set of tools.

Comment: The compression switch, `-z` is more useful for network transfers and can be left off for `rsync`'s between local filesystem.